# Using a function's argument to get the value of the substructure

Tags: matlab

```
function found = find(property)
    res = 0;
    if subject(1).property == 20
        res = res + 1;
    end
end
```

Hey guys, I am trying to get the substructure to be identified through this function's argument. Any ideas on how to implement this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if subject(1).(property) == 20
```

I finally figured it out, I just had to put parentheses.